# Delete SQL statement not functioning

Tags: sql, ms-access

I receive “Syntax Error in FROM clause”

Any help/ideas are greatly appreciated, I’m a beginner if you can’t tell!

CODE is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_click()
Dim sql As String, rCount As Integer
If me.dirty then
Me.dirty = False
End if
Set dbs = currentdb
SQL = “DELETE Item FROM item = ‘“ & me.txtItem & “‘“ &                  “WHERE ID=“ & me.txtID2

Dbs.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
rCount = dbs.RecordsAffected
If rCount >0 then
Msgbox “The item List has been updated”
List40.Requery
Clear
End if
End sub
```

Comment: Please don't build up SQL queries via string concatenation. That leads to SQL Injection.

Comment: What is the name of the table you are trying to delete from? How would you identify the row(s) to delete (column name and type, value)?

Comment: The table is "Item" and the .field is Item the field consists of auto parts

Comment: After double click "listbox" info is placed in textbox "txtItem" and Id is placed in txtID2

Comment: sorry yes ms-access

Comment: That delete command should look like `DELETE FROM <table> WHERE <column> = <value>`, with the names in `<>` replaced by the correct values, and possibly quotes around the value. Make sure spaces are in the correct places when you concatenate (inspect the resulting string)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use DELETE in SQL like this.

```
DELETE FROM Item WHERE ID='" + txtID2.Text + "'
```

Where you can delete an item base on the items ID.

Comment: You can assign the value of you ID to a parameter like this. `SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID2.Text)` then the query will call the value of the ID.

Comment: When I change the sql statement as both of you suggested, it still doesn’t function.

Comment: @skooter "doesn't function" does not say much. Do you get any errors? Please specify.

Comment: @Unknown Be [careful with AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Looks like the OP is currently using [`Database.Execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-execute-method-dao) in Access. Makes parameterization more difficult. Don't think it has named parameters and I don't think *this method* has a means of passing parameters.

Comment: `@ID` doesn't look like Access.

Comment: I have edited the code so you don't have to assign the value of ID to a parameter instead it's call the textbox where in contains the ID.

Answer (score 1):

`FROM` must refer to a table (whether a physical table you've built, a stored query, or the result of an embedded SQL string).
`FROM item = ‘“ & me.txtItem & “‘“` in your code has no meaning to SQL.

This avoids the string concatenation to build up your SQL - just pass the value as a parameter and then execute the query:

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS Identifier TEXT (255); " & _
        "DELETE * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = Identifier")

    With qdf
        .Parameters("Identifier") = Me.txtID2
        .Execute
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: When I use this i received the following: Runtime Error (3464) Datatype Mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Sorry, misread the SQL in your question.  `ID` is a numeric field so replace `TEXT (255)` with `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

I have Read your Question the Error in the Your SQL QUERY Try This:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.CommandText ="DELETE FROM Item WHERE  ID='"+txtyoutextbox.Text.Trim()+"';
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a userform with ability to delete from unbound textbox with ID textbox associated. What is best way?

Comment: you can get textboxbox value and store into int variable       int id=Convert.ToInt32(txtyourtextboxname.text);

THen Fire the Query Like 

DELETE FROM Item WHERE ID='"+id+"  
OR            
DELETE FROM Item WHERE ID='"+Convert.ToInt32(txtyourtextboxname.text.Trim())+";

Comment: I have Updated My answer try this in your application replace  txtyoutextbox to your textbox name...

Comment: `+txtyoutextbox.Text.Trim()+` doesn't look like VBA syntax.

Comment: But the tag was c# so used c# syntax

Comment: Ah, ok.  Was wondering why two answers seemed to be using the wrong syntax.  I must've joined the party late - it's changed to MS Access now.

Comment: yeah the FIrst code looks like vb,then like C# AND Now is in MS Access- #Darren Bartrup-Cook